# Рандом выдает одни и те же числа

Tags: c#

```
 private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
            var stringChars = new char[22];
            var random = new Random();

            for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
            {
                stringChars[i] = chars[random.Next()];
            }

            textBox3.Text = new String(stringChars);           
            textBox4.Text = new String(stringChars);
        }
```

Comment: `var random = new Random();` - нужно сделать приватным статич.полем, а не каждый раз при нажатии на кнопку создавать заново экземпляр `Random`.

Comment: Как у тебя вообще работает программа. chars[random.Next()] без указания int  min и int max, у тебя рандом может выдать большее число, что не может соответствовать твоему массиву. Будет ошибка "Индекс находился вне границ массива."  Напиши так chars[random.Next(0, 62)], тогда у тебя будет выводить строку из 22 символов, а Next(0, 62) будет выдавать все символы из  string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

Comment: @Sergey_73, я Вам благодарен!

Comment: @АнтонРябухин, Да не за что)